# Synced files on OneDrive if a user's permission got removed from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, onedrive

What will happen inside the synced OneDrive files if the user's permission got removed from SharePoint.

1. let say user A have contribute permission on siteA, and he synced files from the SharePoint site into his overdrive desktop app.
2. and he chose to always show the files on his desktop.
3. then UserA's permission got removed from the SharePoint site >> so what will happen to the files inside the OneDrive app? will the user be able to view those files? or those files will also get removed from his OneDrive app, since he no longer can view them inside SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

If the user permission has been removed from SharePoint, the user will not be able to see files in OneDrive app.

These files will also get removed from his OneDrive app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are the files still available if the user does not connect to the Internet after the permissions are revoked?
I think the following scenario is possible. Suppose the user permissions are revoked. The user however does not connect to the Internet, the local files are still available and the user can copy them to a USB drive. For organisations that handle sensitive information this is something to be aware off.
Paul